# How can I make a custom query directive in Apollo

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, graphql-tag

The GraphQL specification allows us to add custom query directives. I'm looking for some information on how can I do this. I want to create a  `@include` like a directive, but with more elaborate logic.

Apollo guide describes only adding scheme (i.e. working on the server) directive.

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v2/schema/creating-directives/#what-about-query-directives

Comment: any update on this one? could be very useful

Answer (score -1):

The @include directive can be used to include a field based on the value of the if argument. The query below would only include the authors for a post if includeAuthor GraphQL variable has a value true.

GraphQL Query

```
query ($includeAuthor: Boolean!) {
    queryPost {
    id
    title
    text
    author @include(if: $includeAuthor) {
        id
        name
    }
  }
}
```

GraphQL variables

```
{
   "includeAuthor": false
}
```

Comment: I need a custom directive